# What does it mean by 'preassigned orientation'?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I want to solve the next exercise of graph theory:

*Prove that a transitive tournament contains a Hamilton path with any preassigned orientation*

My problem is that I don't understand what the exercise means by 'any preassigned orientation'. I do not know what I must prove...

Comment: An orientation on a graph is a choice of direction of each of its vertices. Preassigned means picked before you go about looking for the Hamiltonian path. Seems like the "with any preassigned orientation" is redundant.

Comment: So... what must I prove?... becuase there's a theorem on the book that states that any tournament containts a Hamiltonian path, so this exercise is obvious, and the 'transitive' hypotesis is never used